# How do i insert multiple tables into a table using TinyDB?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tinydb

I have been trying to create multiple tables in a table using TinyDB. Here is a website to help you understand what TinyDb is ([TinyDB PDF](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/tinydb/latest/tinydb.pdf)). The PDF file did not show how to insert multiple tables into one, one multiple data into one table.

I intended the json file to look like this:

```
"MASTER TABLE": 
{
     {"TABLE 1": {"1": {"Name": "Alice", "Age": 19}}
     {"TABLE 2": {"1": {"Name": "John", "Age": 12}}, 
}
```

However, the issue is that I'm not sure how to insert Table1 and Table2 into the Master file table. SO it gave me the error that table1 is not an element. I know it isn't an element but I don't have any idea of how to fix it, to put the two tables under the Master file table. I'd appreciate any help.

Here's my codes:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from tinydb import TinyDB, where
import json

with open("/home/pi/Desktop/jsontest/test.json", 'w+'):
    table1 = TinyDB('/home/pi/Desktop/jsontest/test.json')
    table1 = table1.table('TABLE 1')
    table1.insert_multiple([{'Name' : 'Alice' , 'Age' : 19}])

    table2 = TinyDB('/home/pi/Desktop/jsontest/test.json')
    table2 = table2.table('TABLE 2')
    table2.insert_multiple([{'Name' : 'john' , 'Age' : 12}])

    overall = TinyDB('/home/pi/Desktop/jsontest/test.json')
    overall = overall.table('MASTER TABLE')
    overall.insert([table1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to insert tables into another table ?

```
from tinydb import TinyDB

db = TinyDB('db.json')

table1 = db.table('TABLE 1')
table1.insert({'Name' : 'Alice' , 'Age' : 19})

table2 = db.table('TABLE 2')
table2.insert({'Name' : 'john' , 'Age' : 12})
```

Gives **db.json** containing:

```
{
   "_default": {}, 
   "TABLE 1": {"1": {"Name": "Alice", "Age": 19}}, 
   "TABLE 2": {"1": {"Name": "john", "Age": 12}}
}
```

I think your JSON is incorrect, you cannot the syntax (key, value) here:

```
"MASTER TABLE": 
{
    {"TABLE 1": {"1": {"Name": "Alice", "Age": 19}}
    {"TABLE 2": {"1": {"Name": "John", "Age": 12}}, 
}
```

You can do that:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB

db = TinyDB('db.json', default_table='MASTER TABLE')

master_table = db.table('MASTER TABLE')
master_table.insert({"TABLE 1": {"1": {"Name": "Alice", "Age": 19}}})
master_table.insert({"TABLE 2": {"1": {"Name": "John", "Age": 12}}})
```

You obtain **db.json** containing:

```
{
  "MASTER TABLE": {
      "1": {"TABLE 1": {"1": {"Name": "Alice", "Age": 19}}}, 
      "2": {"TABLE 2": {"1": {"Name": "John", "Age": 12}}}
  }
}
```

But it is strange.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who just want to check if the database has any tables or not you can use the following code *(I looked for the answer to my question but this thread popped up so I thought others with same question might visit this thread in future)*:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB

connection = TinyDB(self.current_directory  + self.database_name)
connection_str = str(connection).split(',')
_, _, tail = connection_str[1].partition('=')
if int(tail) == 0:
    print("INFO: No tables in the database.")
```